# Is there a range view to iterate over intersection of two maps and perform functions with the common key and the two values

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, range, range-v3

Assume we have two maps with some common keys but different values, I would like to iterate over the "intersection" of two maps, where the key are the same. Then I would like to perform a transform function `f(key, value_in_map1, value_in_map2)`.

I would like to do it using `range views`, so that I can pipeline further. I tried `ranges::views::set_intersection` in range-v3, but it does not work as expected:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main () {
    std::map<int, int> m1 {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
    std::map<int, int> m2 {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}};

    auto res = ranges::views::set_intersection(m1, m2);
    for(auto&& p : res) {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
        // output: 0 0
    }

    /* Here is what I expect for the desired view
    auto res = map_intersection(m1, m2);
    for(auto&& [key, value_in_m1, value_in_m2] : res) {
        std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
        // expected output:
        // 0 0 0
        // 2 2 1
    }
    // my desired syntax
    map_intersection(m1, m2) 
      | ranges::views::transform([](int key, int value_in_m1, int value_in_m2) {
                                      // use the values here
        })
      | more_views
    */

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3cbMY9n7b shows the above code.

If such a view (`map_intersection` in the above commented code) does not exist in range-v3, how to implement it?

---

**Update (Jan 05, 2024)**

I followed @fdan's suggestion (thanks) and used the implementation of `views::set_intersection` to create a new view `views::set_intersection_return_both`, which returns both iterators' values instead of only the first one.

The main implementation idea is:

- implementing `set_intersection_return_both_cursor` based on `set_intersection_cursor` using public inheritance.
- set the right return_value: `using value_type = std::pair<range_value_t<R1>, range_value_t<R2>>;`
- implement `read` function:

```
            auto CPP_auto_fun(read)()(const)
            (
                return value_type{*it1_, *it2_}
            )
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/s9b7d4h1n for the implementation and example usages.

The view works well in for-loop and binding back pipeline syntax. However, it still has issues to pipeline further with `views::transform`.

---

**Update (Jan 08, 2024)**

After further understanding the `zip_view`, I make my implementation work for pipeline now, see
https://godbolt.org/z/bexEvan7M (I change my view's name to `set_intersection_zip`)

The main change is to add a `move` function and the `rvalue_type`.

Here is the major part of the implementation (the rest can be found in https://godbolt.org/z/bexEvan7M)

```cpp
    /// \cond
    namespace detail {
        template<bool IsConst, typename Rng1, typename Rng2, typename C, typename P1,
                 typename P2>
        struct set_intersection_zip_cursor
          : public set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>
        {
          private:
            friend struct set_intersection_cursor_return_both<!IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>;
            using set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::it1_;
            using set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::it2_;
            using pred_ref_ = typename set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::pred_ref_;
            using proj1_ref_ = typename set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::proj1_ref_;
            using proj2_ref_ = typename set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::proj2_ref_;
            using R1 = typename set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::R1;
            using R2 = typename set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>::R2;

          public:
            using value_type = common_pair<iter_reference_t<decltype(it1_)>, iter_reference_t<decltype(it2_)>>;
            using rvalue_type = common_pair<iter_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(it1_)>, iter_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(it2_)>>;
            using single_pass = meta::or_c<single_pass_iterator_<iterator_t<R1>>,
                                           single_pass_iterator_<iterator_t<R2>>>;
            set_intersection_zip_cursor() = default;
            set_intersection_zip_cursor(pred_ref_ pred, proj1_ref_ proj1, proj2_ref_ proj2,
                                    iterator_t<R1> it1, sentinel_t<R1> end1,
                                    iterator_t<R2> it2, sentinel_t<R2> end2)
                : set_intersection_cursor<IsConst, Rng1, Rng2, C, P1, P2>(pred, proj1, proj2, it1, end1, it2, end2) {}
            // clang-format off
            auto CPP_auto_fun(read)()(const)
            (
                return value_type{*it1_, *it2_}
            )
            auto CPP_auto_fun(move)()(const)
            (
                return rvalue_type{iter_move(it1_), iter_move(it2_)}
            )
            // clang-format on
        };
    } // namespace detail
    /// \endcond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no view or algorithm available in v3 or the STL for this. The main problem is that all `set_*` functions only return the value from the first range. In your example, you're comparing the pair of the map, so you only get `0 0` as a result. You can fix this by using custom projectors or a custom comparator, but then you would get `0 0` and `2 2` (from the first range) with `2 1` (from the second range) missing.

What you need is something like `set_intersection_transform`, which transforms both iterators before returning the result. Writing such a view with v3 is difficult, you can look at the existing [source](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/set_algorithm.hpp) and the [manual](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) on how to write custom views. Implementing such a a view is probably out of scope for SO.

As an alternative you can calculate the intersection twice and then zip both results (and eventually transform them further). This is *redundant* work, but equal in terms of time complexity.

```cpp
std::map<int, int> m1{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
std::map<int, int> m2{{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}};

auto proj = &std::map<int, int>::value_type::first;
auto v1 = ranges::views::set_intersection(m1, m2, {}, proj, proj);
auto v2 = ranges::views::set_intersection(m2, m1, {}, proj, proj);

// 0 0 0
// 2 2 1
for (const auto& [m1_pair, m2_pair] : ranges::views::zip(v1, v2)) {
  std::cout << m1_pair.first << " " << m1_pair.second << " " << m2_pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I followed your suggestion and implemented such a view, see my updates and https://godbolt.org/z/s9b7d4h1n